# Is there a way to get the actual time in UST (ignoring user settings) in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, date, react-native

I'm currently working on a bug where the user manually sets their timezone and then manually sets the time within that timezone (say, 3 hours behind). This causes the system to use the user's time (which is 3 hours behind UST). Due to this, any calls to a Javascript or React Native library will return a time that is 3 hours behind the actual time. This causes issues when dealing with API calls to my server which returns the actual time in UST

I've tried using Date objects, the I18n library, and just about everything in between. I'm trying to find a universal fix for both Android and iOS since this is a part of my cross-platform codebase.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean "UTC" instead of "UST"?

Comment: ECMAScript is dependent on the host environment, it only has the resources that the host provides. If you want anything else, you'll need access to a different resource (if the host allows it).

Answer (score 0):

The libraries get the time from the client, how about getting the time from an external source? You can use this API: https://timezonedb.com/api

Another possibility is storing and updating a time offset, so you can calculate the actual time from the current time that is set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to reduce external dependencies and API calls (since I have to go through a huge approval process to implement a new API), but I'll give it a shot. I probably should have mentioned that in the original post, my bad!

Comment: How about keeping track of the offset from the real time every time the user changes the time? Store/update the offset and use it to calculate the real time whenever you need to.